# How to plot GIS databases in Python with Basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I need to plot a shapefile in Python, which is supposed to be as simple as this:

```
m = Basemap(...)
m.readshapefile(path/filename,'.shp',...)
```

However, the data I need is included in a GIS database without any .shp file (you can download it from [here](https://earthquake.usgs.gov/static/lfs/nshm/qfaults/Qfaults_GIS.zip)). I have no idea how to plot this data with Basemap, for I have zero knowledge about GIS. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Looks like you'd need to convert the `.gdb` folder to a more usable format. [This](https://gis.ucla.edu/node/53) looks promising.

Comment: Thank you @gherka, do you know whether it's possible to make the conversion in python?

Comment: As long as you have the correct drivers, `geopandas` or `fiona` should be able to handle the conversion to ESRI shapefiles which you can feed to `Basemap`. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193533/troubleshooting-file-geodatabase-parsing-in-python-fiona) might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much @gherka. It is a pity that it's a nightmare to install geopandas and I keep getting errors. Anyway, this is another issue. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! (Thanks to @gherka 's suggestion)

1. Import geopandas and fiona, and check if 'OpenFileGDB' is among the supported drivers:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona

fiona.supported_drivers
```

2. Convert the .gdb file to .shp (you may need to specify the layer to convert, as for my case!):

```
faults = gpd.read_file('./Qfaults_2020_WGS84.gdb/', layer=1)
faults.to_file("faults.shp")
```

3. Plot the .shp file with Basemap:

```
    m = Basemap(projection='merc', resolution='i', llcrnrlon=llcrnrlon, llcrnrlat=llcrnrlat,
                urcrnrlon=urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat=urcrnrlat)
    m.readshapefile('./faults', '.shp', linewidth=0.25, color='r', default_encoding='ISO8859-1')
```